# SshStream.Expect() breaks code when SshStream is no longer valid

Tags: c#, ssh.net

Im trying to do automation over SSH but the server is faulty and does not implement exec channel properly so I ended up doing a workaround using `CreateShellStream()`. I can expect that upon running the program a connection wouldnt be available and disconnections are a thing. My solution:

```
while(!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested))
{
    ShellStream stream = null;
    while(stream == null)
    {
        stream = await GetSshStream();
    }
    while(stream.CanWrite && stream.CanRead)
    {
        stream.WriteLine(command);
        //this breaks everything if stream is not valid
        var rep = stream.Expect(new Regex(@"[$>]")); 
        var delimiters = new[] { " ", "\r\n", "\t" };
        var values = rep.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        DealWithValues(values);
    }
}
```

This works and waits for connection and once connected starts coms. The problem arises with that `stream.CanWrite && stream.CanRead` is not enough to detect that `stream` is healthy and once connection is lost and stream becomes invalid and used with `Expect();` everything breaks. Jumps out of all loops, goes through `try {} catch{}` and even makes Visual Studio debugger steping break down and continue the program in another thread (multi threaded program). Is there a way to stop this from happening and throwing execution back to first `while`? I could possibly create a new stream every time I need access to the server but since Im polling parameters about once a second I wouldnt want to have the overhead of reconnecting each time.

Answer (score 0):

I misundertood that thread dissapearing ment code execution stopped. Instead thread sleeps waiting for input. `Expect` has a timeout overload and I should of been using it.